# Getting a dropdown menu to update based on a variable

Tags: python, drop-down-menu, tkinter, updating

I am attempting to create a database management system with the ability to delete accounts. I can get the drop down menu to display the current list of users, but I don't understand how to make it show the new list of users. The code for the dropdown menu is as follows:

```
import tkinter
from tkinter import *

tkwindow = Tk()
tkwindow.title
users = ['user1','user2','user3']

def callback(*args):
    name = var.get()
    print ('%s' % name)
    users.remove(name)
    print (users)
    option.setitems(*users)

var = StringVar(tkwindow)
var.trace("w", callback)
option = OptionMenu(tkwindow, var, *users)
option.pack()
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the Menu option of the `OptionMenu`. For example if you get the index of the `name` string, you can delete that from the `OptionMenu` using the code below.

```
def callback(*args):
    name = var.get()
    print ('%s' % name)
    users.remove(name)
    print (users)
    menu = option['menu']
    menu.delete(menu.index(name))
```

Comment: I've encountered an issue when changing the code to import users from a text file. If you choose the second account option in the drop down menu, it doesn't delete. For example, if users imports [1,2,3] and you attempt to delete 2, it deletes 3 and still shows 2 in the menu.